# Facebook social share popup shrink in iPhone safari when start typing - Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, socialshare

We are using javascript SDK of Facebook for social share. Everything works fine, but in iPhone safari, when a user starts typing, the pop up get smaller and a user can no longer see the text area. The text area gets to hide. Look the image for reference.

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcUzq.png)